# std::array: size and max_size returns same number thought the element in array are less

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

As we can see from the below code that the maximum element in the array are the same as that of size. I was expecting the `size` will return me the 2 elements only.

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

enum class x
{
    a = 1,
    b = 2,
    c = 3
};

int main()
{ 
    std::array<x, 3> nums {x::a, x::b};

    std::cout << "nums contains " << nums.size() << " elements.\n";
    std::cout << "max nums contains " << nums.max_size() << " elements.\n";
}
```

Result:

```
nums contains 3 elements.
max nums contains 3 elements.
```

Why the size and max_size return the same value?

Comment: The third element is `0`.

Comment: an array has fixed number of elements. If you ask for an array with 3 elements you get an array with 3 elements

Comment: not easy to write an answer, because it isnt 100% clear where exactly is your misunderstanding. Perhaps it would be easier if you actually ask a question ;)

Comment: `size` returns 3 because the fixed-size array has 3 elements.  `max_size` returns 3 because the fixed-size array has fixed-size of 3 elements.

Answer (score 1):

> I was expecting the size will return me the 2 elements only

Arrays do not work this way. Size of an array always equals to its capacity.

If you want `vector` with fixed capacity, you probably need `boost::container::static_vector`. There isn't such standard container, there's a proposal [p0843](http://wg21.link/p0843) however.

Comment: `max_size` is distinct from `capacity`. A vector's max size is derived from the platform's limits on contiguous allocation

Comment: Sure. But for `std::array` as well as for `static_vector` (both boost and currently proposed for std) `max_size` equals to `capacity`.